# cocos2d-x android build failed

Tags: android, c++, build, cocos2d-x

I'm sorry I have to depend on Google Translator because I can not speak English well.

I built the cocos2d-x project using the cocos compile -p android --android-studio command.

My development environment:
    OS = Windows10
    cocos2d-x = 3.17.1
    ndk = r11c
    sdk = 27.0.3 (android studio version = latest ( 3.2.1 ) )

How to fix this build error?

```
> Task :gamer:generateJsonModelDebug FAILED
Task ':gamer:generateJsonModelDebug' is not up-to-date because:
  No history is available.
External native generate JSON debug: starting JSON generation
External native generate JSON debug: using platform version 16 for ABI 
ARMEABI_V7A and min SDK version 16
External native generate JSON debug: rebuilding JSON C:\Development\cocos2d- 
x-3.17.1\tools\cocos2d- 
console\bin\gamer\proj.android\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\armeabi- 
v7a\android_gradle_build.json due to:
External native generate JSON debug: - expected json C:\Development\cocos2d- 
x-3.17.1\tools\cocos2d- 
console\bin\gamer\proj.android\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\armeabi- 
v7a\android_gradle_build.json file is not present, will remove stale json 
folder
External native generate JSON debug: - missing previous command file 
C:\Development\cocos2d-x-3.17.1\tools\cocos2d- 
console\bin\gamer\proj.android\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\armeabi- 
v7a\cmake_build_command.txt, will remove stale json folder
External native generate JSON debug: removing stale contents from 
'C:\Development\cocos2d-x-3.17.1\tools\cocos2d- 
console\bin\gamer\proj.android\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\armeabi- 
v7a'
External native generate JSON debug: created folder 'C:\Development\cocos2d- 
x-3.17.1\tools\cocos2d- 
console\bin\gamer\proj.android\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\armeabi- 
v7a'
External native generate JSON debug: executing cmake Executable : 
C:\Development\sdk\cmake\3.10.2.4988404\bin\cmake.exe
arguments :
-HC:\Development\cocos2d-x-3.17.1\tools\cocos2d-console\bin\gamer
-BC:\Development\cocos2d-x-3.17.1\tools\cocos2d- 

console\bin\gamer\proj.android\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\armeabi- 
v7a
-DANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a
-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-16
-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Development\cocos2d-x- 
 3.17.1\tools\cocos2d- 



 > Task :gamer:generateJsonModelDebug FAILED
Task ':gamer:generateJsonModelDebug' is not up-to-date because:
  No history is available.
External native generate JSON debug: starting JSON generation
External native generate JSON debug: using platform version 16 for ABI 
ARMEABI_V7A and min SDK version 16
External native generate JSON debug: rebuilding JSON C:\Development\cocos2d- 
x-3.17.1\tools\cocos2d- 
console\bin\gamer\proj.android\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\armeabi- 
v7a\android_gradle_build.json due to:
External native generate JSON debug: - expected json C:\Development\cocos2d- 
x-3.17.1\tools\cocos2d- 
console\bin\gamer\proj.android\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\armeabi- 
v7a\android_gradle_build.json file is not present, will remove stale json 
folder
External native generate JSON debug: - missing previous command file 
C:\Development\cocos2d-x-3.17.1\tools\cocos2d-
```

console\bin\gamer\proj.android\app.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\armeabi- 
   v7a\cmake_build_command.txt, will remove stale json folder
    External native generate JSON debug: removing stale contents from 
    'C:\Development\cocos2d-x-3.17.1\tools\cocos2d- 
   console\bin\gamer\proj.android\app.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\armeabi- 
   v7a'
    External native generate JSON debug: created folder 'C:\Development\cocos2d- 
   x-3.17.1\tools\cocos2d- 
   console\bin\gamer\proj.android\app.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\armeabi- 
   v7a'
    External native generate JSON debug: executing cmake Executable : 
    C:\Development\sdk\cmake\3.10.2.4988404\bin\cmake.exe
    arguments :
    -HC:\Development\cocos2d-x-3.17.1\tools\cocos2d-console\bin\gamer
    -BC:\Development\cocos2d-x-3.17.1\tools\cocos2d- 
    console\bin\gamer\proj.android\app.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\armeabi- 
    v7a
    -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a
    -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-16
    -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Development\cocos2d-x- 
    3.17.1\tools\cocos2d-

console\bin\gamer\proj.android\app\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\armeabi- 
    v7a
    -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
    -DANDROID_NDK=C:\Development\android-ndk-r11c
    -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-frtti -fexceptions -fsigned-char
    -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Android
    -DCMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI=armeabi-v7a
    -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION=16
    -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON
    -DCMAKE_ANDROID_NDK=C:\Development\android-ndk-r11c
    -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\Development\cocos2d-x-3.17.1\tools\cocos2d- 
    console\bin\gamer\proj.android\app.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\armeabi- 
    v7a\pre-ndk-r15-wrapper-android.toolchain.cmake
    -G Ninja
    -DCMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH=
    -DANDROID_STL=c++_static
    -DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang
    -DANDROID_ARM_NEON=TRUE
    jvmArgs :

```
[== "CMake Server" ==[
```

{"supportedProtocolVersions":[{"isExperimental":true,"major":1,"minor":1}],"type":"hello"}

]== "CMake Server" ==]

[== "CMake Server" ==[

{
  "type": "handshake",
  "cookie": "gradle-cmake-cookie",
  "protocolVersion": {
    "isExperimental": true,
    "major": 1,
    "minor": 1
  },
  "sourceDirectory": "C:/Development/cocos2d-x-3.17.1/tools/cocos2d-console/bin/gamer",
  "buildDirectory": "C:/Development/cocos2d-x-3.17.1/tools/cocos2d-console/bin/gamer/proj.android/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/armeabi-v7a",
  "generator": "Ninja"
}

]== "CMake Server" ==]

[== "CMake Server" ==[

{"cookie":"gradle-cmake-cookie","inReplyTo":"handshake","type":"reply"}

]== "CMake Server" ==]

[== "CMake Server" ==[

{
  "type": "configure",
  "cacheArguments": [
    "",
    "-DANDROID_ABI\u003darmeabi-v7a",
    "-DANDROID_PLATFORM\u003dandroid-16",
    "-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY\u003dC:\Development\cocos2d-x-3.17.1\tools\cocos2d-console\bin\gamer\proj.android\app\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\armeabi-v7a",
    "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE\u003dDebug",
    "-DANDROID_NDK\u003dC:\Development\android-ndk-r11c",
    "-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS\u003d-frtti -fexceptions -fsigned-char",
    "-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME\u003dAndroid",
    "-DCMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI\u003darmeabi-v7a",
    "-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION\u003d16",
    "-DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS\u003dON",
    "-DCMAKE_ANDROID_NDK\u003dC:\Development\android-ndk-r11c",
    "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE\u003dC:\Development\cocos2d-x-3.17.1\tools\cocos2d-console\bin\gamer\proj.android\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\armeabi-v7a\pre-ndk-r15-wrapper-android.toolchain.cmake",
    "-G Ninja",
    "-DCMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH\u003d",
    "-DANDROID_STL\u003dc++_static",
    "-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN\u003dclang",
    "-DANDROID_ARM_NEON\u003dTRUE"
  ]
}

]== "CMake Server" ==]

[== "CMake Server" ==[

{"cookie":"","inReplyTo":"configure","message":"CMake Error at C:/Development/sdk/cmake/3.10.2.4988404/android.toolchain.cmake:356 (message):\n  Invalid Android NDK revision (should be 12): 11.2.2725575.\nCall Stack (most recent call first):\n  proj.android/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/armeabi-v7a/pre-ndk-r15-wrapper-android.toolchain.cmake:2 (include)\n  C:/Development/sdk/cmake/3.10.2.4988404/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:94 (include)\n  CMakeLists.txt:30 (project)\n\n","title":"Error","type":"message"}

]== "CMake Server" ==]

CMake Error at C:/Development/sdk/cmake/3.10.2.4988404/android.toolchain.cmake:356 (message):
  Invalid Android NDK revision (should be 12): 11.2.2725575.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  proj.android/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/armeabi-v7a/pre-ndk-r15-wrapper-android.toolchain.cmake:2 (include)
  C:/Development/sdk/cmake/3.10.2.4988404/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:94 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:30 (project)

CMake Error at C:/Development/sdk/cmake/3.10.2.4988404/android.toolchain.cmake:356 (message):
  Invalid Android NDK revision (should be 12): 11.2.2725575.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  proj.android/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/armeabi-v7a/pre-ndk-r15-wrapper-android.toolchain.cmake:2 (include)
  C:/Development/sdk/cmake/3.10.2.4988404/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:94 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:30 (project)

[== "CMake Server" ==[

{"cookie":"","inReplyTo":"configure","message":"CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to \"Ninja\".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.","title":"Error","type":"message"}

]== "CMake Server" ==]

CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Ninja".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Ninja".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.

[== "CMake Server" ==[

{"cookie":"","inReplyTo":"configure","message":"CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage","title":"Error","type":"message"}

]== "CMake Server" ==]

CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage

[== "CMake Server" ==[

{"cookie":"","inReplyTo":"configure","message":"CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage","title":"Error","type":"message"}

]== "CMake Server" ==]

CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage

[== "CMake Server" ==[

{"cookie":"","inReplyTo":"configure","progressCurrent":1000,"progressMaximum":1000,"progressMessage":"Configuring","progressMinimum":0,"type":"progress"}

]== "CMake Server" ==]

[== "CMake Server" ==[

{"cookie":"","inReplyTo":"configure","message":"Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!","type":"message"}

]== "CMake Server" ==]

Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

[== "CMake Server" ==[

{"cookie":"","errorMessage":"Configuration failed.","inReplyTo":"configure","type":"error"}

]== "CMake Server" ==]

Configuration failed.
External native generate JSON debug: JSON generation completed with problems

:gamer:generateJsonModelDebug (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 7,5,main]) completed. Took 0.2 secs.

> Task :libcocos2dx:platformAttrExtractor
>   Task ':libcocos2dx:platformAttrExtractor' is not up-to-date because:
>     No history is available.

:libcocos2dx:platformAttrExtractor (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 5,5,main]) completed. Took 0.232 secs.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':gamer:generateJsonModelDebug'.

  > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error configuring
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 21s
21 actionable tasks: 21 executed
Error running command, return code: 1.

What's wrong with me?

Comment: Did you do any of the things suggested at the end of the error?

Comment: I do not know what to do.

Answer (score 3):

> CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to
>   "Ninja".

`cocos2d-x 3.17.1` using CMake, cross-platform build system(by default).

Google mostly upgrade missing dependencies by automatic downloading in SDK. 
e.g. CMake was upgraded from `3.6` to `3.10`(ninja required in latest cMake).

so you've to **install Ninja in your system**.

- If you're Window system user, [download and extract](https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja/releases/download/v1.9.0/ninja-win.zip) Ninja.exe and set in environment path.
- If you're MacOS user you can [install ninja in your system](http://macappstore.org/ninja/) by brew.

I hope this solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

macOS 10.15 + cpp3171 + ndk-r16b

```
brew install ninja
cocos compile -p android
```